# Is it enough that my SpringBoot API is published on a EC2 server with HTTPS to be secure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, amazon-ec2

Is it enough that my API is published on a server with HTTPS to be secure?

I have an API built with JAVA + SpringBoot, it has the security of a SECRET, that is, for example, when I make a POST request from my mobile application, in the POST header I send a TOKEN which is a secret that in the backend (Java + SpringBoot) would be validating if the SECRET is correct.

It is then that I would like to know if by deploying my API on an AWS EC2 server which has HTTPS encryption, this would be enough so that my API requests cannot be inspected and that secret token is "stolen" giving them the green light to consume my API freely outside my mobile application.

Currently, how the API is built and since I am still working in localhost with the Backend in development mode, the requests to the backend go through HTTP (Not HTTPS) and I can inspect everything about the request to my API, it is then that I would like to encrypt all this and that the "SECRET TOKEN" cannot be visualized.

I plan to make API requests from mobile applications made in React Native as well as from a web page.

So I wonder if deploying to an AWS EC2 server with HTTPS security would fix this.

Comment: Enough to ensure that someone else on the network can't intercept the secret?  Probably.  Enough to ensure a sufficiently motivated user can't intercept the secret?  [Absolutely not](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99952/how-to-intercepting-ios-https-traffic).